# Subtracting dates in the same row by a factor. R

Tags: r, dataframe, date

I have the following data frame:

```
DF<-data.frame(stringsAsFactors = TRUE,
           Sample = c(rep("s1",4),rep("s2",4)),
           date = c("21/07/2020","24/07/2020","25/07/2020","27/07/2020",
                    "03/08/2020","06/08/2020","09/08/2020","10/08/2020"))
```

First I want to obtain the number of days between consecutive dates by the factor "Sample". so the output would be like this:

```
DF_2<-data.frame(stringsAsFactors = TRUE,
           Sample = c(rep("s1",4),rep("s2",4)),
           date = c("21/07/2020","24/07/2020","25/07/2020","27/07/2020",
                    "03/08/2020","06/08/2020","09/08/2020","10/08/2020"),
           days = c(NA,3,1,2,NA,3,3,1))
```

Where variable "days" is my outcome variable.
Afterwards I want to add all those "days" by factor. But that is easy, will do it like this:

```
df_3<-aggregate(days~Sample,DF_2,sum)
```

I would much appreciate it if someone helps me to get right first step, to get DF_2.

Comment: Is the expected output correct.  Should that be `3, 1, 2` for the last 3 values in 'days'

Comment: Don't think so. From the 03/08/2020 to 06/08/2020 = 3 days; 06/08/2020 to 09/08/2020 = 3 days; 09/08/2020 to 10/08/2020= 1 days. Perhaps I did not explained myself correctly.

Comment: Sorry, you were right, checked!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use `diff` to get the difference between `Date` class converted 'date' column

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)
DF1 <- DF %>%
         mutate(date = dmy(date)) %>% 
         group_by(Sample) %>% 
         mutate(days = c(NA, diff(date))) %>%
         ungroup
```